# Event does not exist for py-papi but event is available for papi_avail

Tags: python, papi

I am following the tutorial [here](http://www.bnikolic.co.uk/blog/python/flops/2019/09/27/python-counting-events.html) for a python wrapper for the [Performance Application Programming Interface](http://icl.cs.utk.edu/papi/index.html).

I can see via `papi_avail` that my system does have hardware counters (`Number Hardware Counters: 11`)  and that the event I am interested in (`PAPI_SP_OPS`) is available:

```
Name        Code       Avail Deriv Description (Note)
PAPI_SP_OPS 0x80000067 Yes   Yes   Floating point operations; optimised to count scaled single precision vector operations
```

Now I run the python wrapper analogous to shown in the tutorial:

```py
from pyapi import events, papi_high as high

high.start_counters([events.PAPI_SP_OPS])
```

However I get the error `pyapi.exceptions.PapiNoEventError: Event does not exist. (PAPI_ENOEVNT)`. But clearly the event does exist as shown at the start with `papi_avail`

Any tips?

Answer (score 1):

This means that the event is available but your python code doesn't access to the Counters in the Hardware.

In my experience, you cannot access the counters in the AWS instances, but if you are running in your local machine, then you should give your environment special privileges.

What I have done is set up a docker container, with the flag "--privileged" and that has solved the issue.